# Floating CSS-I'm probably doing something wrong

Tags: css-float

I'm a newbie in HTML/CSS and i don't know why when i resize my window for less than 480px width, the third "pack" doesn't also float to the left.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaymKP?editors=110

```css
.packages{
 width:92%;
 margin:0 auto;

}
.pack{
    margin-left:-0.483091%;
 width:25.483091%;
 background-color:#e0e0e0;
 border-radius:5px;
 float:left;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

.pack ul li:first-child{
 border-top:none;
}

.pack ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.pack ul li {
 border-top:1px solid #ffffff;
 font:normal 0.83875em Arial,sans-serif;
 color:#797979;
 height:18px;
 padding:13px 0;
}

.pack ul li a{
 display:block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#ffffff;
 font:bold 1.118125em Arial,sans-serif;
 width:72.985781%;
 height:29px;
 background-color:#575757;
 border-radius:20px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top:10px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.pack ul li.last-child{
 border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
 padding:30px 0;
 height:29px;
}

.pack.third_column ul li.last-child{
 height:29px;
 padding:38px 0;

}
.pack .column_top h1,h2{
 color:#ffffff;
}

.pack .column_top h1{
 font:bold 1.3975em Arial,sans-serif;
 padding-top:4px;
}

.pack .column_top h2{
 font:bold 1.1475em Arial,sans-serif;
 margin-top:-6px;
}

.pack .column_top h2 span{
 font:bold 2.1875em Arial,sans-serif;
}

.column_top{
 height:75px;
 border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 4;
}

.column_top sup{
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

.first_column{
 background-color:#cbcbcb; 
}

.first_column .column_top{
 background:url(../images/top_bg_grey.png) repeat-x;
}

.pack.first_column .column_top h1{
 color:#e0e0e0;
 font:bold 1.40625em Arial,sans-serif;
 padding:10px 30px 10px 30px;
}

.pack.first_column ul li{
 border-top:1px solid #a2a2a2;
 color:#5c5c5c;
}

.pack.lateral{
 box-shadow:-4px 0px 10px -5px #000;
}

.pack.lateral .column_top{
 background:url(../images/top_bg_blue.png) repeat-x;
}

.pack.third_column{
 background:#ffffff;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
 z-index: 5;
}

.pack.third_column .column_top{
 background:transparent url(../images/green_shape.png) no-repeat;
 width:100.54%;
 height:98px;
 top:-20px;
 left:-1px;
}

.pack.third_column ul li:first-child{
 margin-top: -22px;
 border-top: none;
}

.pack.third_column ul li{
 border-top:1px solid #dadada;
} 

.pack.third_column ul li a{
 background-color:#e43a22;
}

@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px){
  .pack{
  width:50%;
  margin-top:20px;
 }

 .pack.third_column .column_top{
 background:transparent url(../images/green_shape.png) no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
 height:75px;
 position:static;
 }

 .pack.third_column ul li:first-child{
  margin-top: 0;
 }

 .media ul li{
  padding-left: 0;
 }
 #img_videos,#img_photos,#img_news,#img_schools{
  padding-right: 0;
 }
}
}
```

```html
<div class="packages">
   <div class="pack first_column">
    <div class="column_top">
     <h1>Pes</h1>
    </div>
    <ul>
     <li>Mo</li>
     <li>Mo</li>
     <li>Eqt</li>
     <li>Cnt</li>
     <li>Ole</li>
     <li>Tes</li>
     <li>Gs</li>
     <li class="last-child"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="arrow"/></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="pack lateral second_column">
    <div class="column_top">
     <h1>Sivkage</h1><h2><sup>$</sup><span></span>0<sub>/mo</sub></h2>
    </div>
    <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>1</li>
     <li><img src="images/yes.png" alt="yes"/></li>
     <li><img src="images/no.png" alt="no"/></li>
     <li><img src="images/no.png" alt="no"/></li>
     <li><img src="images/no.png" alt="no"/></li>
     <li><img src="images/no.png" alt="no"/></li>
     <li class="last-child"><a href="#">SIGN UP</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="pack third_column">
    <div class="column_top">
     <h1>Gage</h1><h2><sup>$</sup><span>9</span><sub>/mo</sub></h2>
    </div>
    <ul>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li><img src="images/yes.png" alt="yes"/></li>
     <li><img src="images/no.png" alt="no"/></li>
     <li><img src="images/yes.png" alt="yes"/></li>
     <li><img src="images/no.png" alt="no"/></li>
     <li><img src="images/yes.png" alt="yes"/></li>
     <li class="last-child"><a href="#">SIGN UP</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="pack lateral">
    <div class="column_top">
     <h1>Pre</h1><h2><sup>$</sup><span>1</span><sub>/mo</sub></h2>
    </div>
    <ul>
     <li>Unlimited</li>
     <li>Unlimited</li>
     <li><img src="images/yes.png" alt="yes"/></li>
     <li><img src="images/yes.png" alt="yes"/></li>
     <li><img src="images/yes.png" alt="yes"/></li>
     <li><img src="images/yes.png" alt="yes"/></li>
     <li><img src="images/yes.png" alt="yes"/></li>
     <li class="last-child"><a href="#">SIGN UP</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a fixed height on your li-elements.

```
.pack ul li {
border-top:1px solid #ffffff;
font:normal 0.83875em Arial,sans-serif;
color:#797979;
height:18px;
padding:13px 0;
}
```

Remove it. If you want your packs to have equal height you can add min-height to it:

```
.pack{
margin-left:-0.483091%;
width:25.483091%;
background-color:#e0e0e0;
border-radius:5px;
float:left;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
min-height:570px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I replaced border-top:none for the first li in the pack with 1px transparent and it worked.